# Issue wit checking for time on check

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hi I'm currently having an issue getting the time allocated for the user which is saved on a postgres database. What I'm trying to achieve is when the users duration expires a role is removed I'm wanting to get the time from the database when the check runs but this doesn't seem to be working,

My console is not outputting an error but the check doesn't seem to be running.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=5.0)
async def check_mute(self):
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(750744359632121661)
    restricted = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Restricted")
    members = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name="Members")
    for member in list(guild.members):
        conn = psycopg2.connect(DATABASE_URL, sslmode='require')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT time FROM blacklist WHERE username=%s", (member.id, ))
        restricted_role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Restricted")
        muted_time = cursor.fetchone()
        current_time = dt.datetime.now()
        mute_elapsed_time = current_time - muted_time 
        
        if member.id:
            await member.add_roles(members)
            await member.remove_roles(restricted, reason=f'Restricted role removed by {author.name}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting errors because `tasks` don't throw any errors by default. In order to get some info out of them, you need to write a custom `error handler` for them.

With that said, I do see a few issues that might cause your loop to break.

First of all, the variables `ctx` and `author` are never defined anywhere in your code fragment, but you're using them. This *will* throw errors & interrupt the loop.

Are you starting your loop using `check_mute.start()`? Tasks need to be started before they run, and your code fragment doesn't have this.

> the check doesn't seem to be running

I don't see you checking the time difference anywhere. You said the check didn't happen, but it just isn't there in the first place. You're defining `mute_elapsed_time`, but **never using it to check if enough time has elapsed** or not.

After fixing those, could you put some debug prints in your task to see where it gets & when it stops? If something else is wrong, that might help identify it.

PS. This is unrelated, but you're `get`'ing `restricted_role` in the loop for every member, while you can just do that once above the loop (and you already did do it above the loop, so it's really unnecessary). You're not even using it as far as I can see so consider removing it ^^. That's also the line where the `ctx` is (which doesn't exist) so removing it all together might be a good idea.

Comment: "check if enough time has elapsed" this is mainly my issue at the moment. I'm stuck at this point, I want to be able to check if the the time saved as a timestamp in the database matches on or after current time, If it does remove the role otherwise don't.

Comment: save it as an epoch timestamp & check if one is greater than the other?